# Flutter IOS error: error: no such module 'flutter_config'

Tags: ios, flutter, build, config

I'm having issue when trying to build my flutter project on code magic CI. I'm using Flutter 2.2.3(same issue also happens on 2.8) and Xcode version 12.4(same issue on 13.2)

```
/Users/builder/clone/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:5:8: error: no such module 'flutter_config'
 import flutter_config
        ^
 remark: Incremental compilation has been disabled: it is not compatible with whole module optimization
 remark: Incremental compilation has been disabled: it is not compatible with whole module optimization
 /Users/builder/clone/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:5:8: error: no such module 'flutter_config'
 import flutter_config
        ^
 note: Using new build system
 note: Planning
 note: Build preparation complete
 note: Building targets in dependency order
 /Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')

Encountered error while building for the device.
```

When launching the app locally I'm having another error:

```
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swift_Concurrency'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftFileProvider'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDataDetection'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'AVFAudio'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'DataDetection'
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDataDetection", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDataDetection_$_FBAudienceNetwork in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAudienceNetwork.o)
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDataDetection_$_FBAudienceNetwork)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKAdImpression", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdSKAdNetworkManager.m.o)
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFileProvider", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFileProvider_$_FBAudienceNetwork in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAudienceNetwork.o)
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFileProvider_$_FBAudienceNetwork)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
warning: no rule to process file '/../flutter2/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_config-2.0.0/ios/Classes/BuildDotenvConfig.rb' of type 'text.script.ruby' for architecture 'arm64' (in target 'flutter_config' from project 'Pods')
warning: no rule to process file '/../flutter2/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_config-2.0.0/ios/Classes/BuildXCConfig.rb' of type 'text.script.ruby' for architecture 'arm64' (in target 'flutter_config' from project 'Pods')
warning: no rule to process file '/../flutter2/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_config-2.0.0/ios/Classes/ReadDotEnv.rb' of type 'text.script.ruby' for architecture 'arm64' (in target 'flutter_config' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `ios/Podfile` file, uncomment the `platform` line and give it a value of 11

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'
```

Make sure to make the change in your Xcode as well
[image]

Then in your `ios` directory, run the following commands

```
rm -rf Pods/
rm -rf Podfile.lock
pod install
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help. I already had platform :ios, '11.0' in my podfile.  Also, I tried cleaning dods and lock-file before. Doing this together with changing Ios Deployment target in XCode UI didn't solve the issue.